# How to force passing parameter as a pointer in Go?

Tags: pointers, parameters, struct, go

I am implementing an application layer network protocol which uses JSON in Go.

```
func ReadMessage(conn net.Conn, returnMessage interface{}) bool {
    messageBytes := // read from conn

    error := json.Unmarshal(messageBytes, &returnMessage)
    if error != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

The function takes a struct as its second parameter where the message is unmarshalled. The function can be called like this:

```
msg := MessageType1{}
ok := ReadMessage(conn, &msg)
```

Or without the ampersand (&)

```
msg := MessageType1{}
ok := ReadMessage(conn, msg)
```

which will compile, but not do what is should as the struct is passed as a copy, not as a reference and the original msg will remain empty. So I'd like to force passing the struct by reference and catch this error at compile time.

Changing the parameter type to *interface{} will not compile:

```
cannot use &msg (type *MessageType1) as type *interface {} in function argument:
*interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface
```

Is there some Go style way of doing this correctly?

Comment: Why don't your **return** the red message?

Comment: If you suggest unmarshalling out side of the read function, that would break the abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a way to do this in the function declaration.

You can use [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Kind) though and panic at runtime when the argument is not a pointer.

However maybe you should consider changing the design of your code. The concrete type of the argument should not matter. It either implements the interface you need or not.

Demo: http://play.golang.org/p/7Dw0EkFzbx

Comment: I have several different message types that I'd like one function to handle. As Go doesn't do inheritance, wouldn't that mean that I'd have to implement the ReadMessage for each message type if I declared an Message interface which has ReadMessage function?

Comment: You could define an interface and make your function to accept that interface instead. Then you could use a [type switch](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

Comment: I can't get my head around that way of thinking. Could you demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Why not define the `ReadMessage()` function on a pointer of type `MessageType1{}`? Like `func (m *MessageType1) ReadMessage(conn net.Conn) bool`.

Comment: Then I'd need to do that for each message type separately. And it's the same implementation every time – only type changes.

Comment: Then you could implement an interface ex.` A` and make your method accept as an argument a `*A`. Then make all your structs implement that interface and you can pass them in your function.

Comment: Any way that I could implement the function only once?

`type Message interface {
 ReadMessage(conn net.Conn) bool
}

func (m *Message) ReadMessage(conn net.Conn) bool {
 return readMessage(conn, &m)
}`

Does not work: invalid receiver type *Message (Message is an interface type)

Comment: @juke _And it's the same implementation every time – only type changes_ : Go does not support traditional inheritance, but has a very interesting way of supporting object composition/aggregation. See
 [**Type Embedding**](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) - I believe that will help you. Here is a simple example of [**Embedding in action**](http://play.golang.org/p/635tMPD18b) Also works with interfaces, as you can see there, giving you great flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Since Go 1.18 you can do this using generics:

```
func test[T any](dst *T) {
  //Do something with dst
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce this as `*T` always has the method set of `T`. Thus both implement the interface.
From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

What you can do instead is to use the language's ability to return multiple values in your function, as [Volker already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148511/how-to-force-passing-parameter-as-a-pointer-in-go#comment33609801_22148511):

```
func ReadMessage(conn net.Conn) (interface{}, bool) {
    var returnMessage interface{}
    messageBytes := // read from conn

    error := json.Unmarshal(messageBytes, &returnMessage)
    if error != nil {
        return nil, false
    }

    return returnMessage, true
}
```

You should also consider not returning type `interface{}` but some meaningful type.

Comment: In this method the type of the type of message that is expected can no be passed to the function. Your implementation returns a map[string]interface{}. In the protocol each message type has different fields so it can't be one type.

Comment: @juke Well, you should have said so in your question :)